# Debugging 2 servers with php's Xdebug at the same time

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have a PHP script that is sending a series of http requests to another php script on another server.   I have Xdebug installed on both servers and I'm using NetBeans as my debug client.  The problem I am having is that NetBeans can't have 2 debug sessions at the same time and you can't spawn 2 NetBeans processes on the same machine.  Am I going to have to run Eclipse and NetBeans at the same time?(YUCK!)  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get another machine, install Netbeans on it, and connect each server to its own debugger. This will help you understand what's happening much better.

Alternate approach: install a virtual machine inside your box, put Netbeans there.

Comment: I am using VMs for development.  Thanks for the advice.